# How to fix the column name with $Resources?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, feature-activation, resources, language-pack

We are using SP2016 on-premise. English (United States) is the base language. I have just enabled Custom Tiles feature for a site:
Enable-SPFeature -Identity CustomTiles -Url http://web_app

It created a hidden list https://web_app/Lists/Custom%20Tiles/

But the column name are:

- Title
- $Resources:spscore,CustomTilesList_Feature_Tile_Order;
- $Resources:spscore,CustomTilesList_Feature_Url;
- $Resources:spscore,CustomTilesList_Feature_Icon_Url;
- $Resources:spscore,CustomTilesList_Feature_Audiences;
- $Resources:spscore,CustomTilesList_Feature_TileSwitch;

It is not the first time I see these kind of problem. It usually happen when I add a new feature (e.g. add SSRS SharePoint mode) to existing SharePoint on-premise farm.

Are there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the **language patch** of your current [update](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates#sharepoint-2016-update-history).

See the reference here: [Custom Tiles in SharePoint Servers 2016.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/38f31e8a-956d-46ba-ba27-ba0a30184746/custom-tiles-in-sharepoint-servers-2016?forum=SP2016)

Comment: I need to update for us english?

Comment: @MarkL Correct.

Comment: Do I need to reinstall the CustomTiles feature after install language pack update?

Comment: @MarkL No, the column names should render soon as you install the language pack.

Comment: Thanks. Although the custom tile is not showing up, the column name is issue is fixed.